# Having issues uploading image path string to User schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm working on a Facebook clone and can't seem to figure out how to upload an image to my `User` schema to use as a profile picture. My hope is to save the image to my database and use the `profilePicture` value in my `User` schema as the `src` path.

Here is my form code, where `user` is my username.

```
<form
    action="/users/<%= user %>/profile-picture"
    method="POST"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
  >
    <input type="file" name="profilePicture" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And here is my `POST` route for uploading.

```
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({ dest: "./public/images/uploads/" });

router.post(
  "/:user/profile-picture",
  upload.single("profilePicture"),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const userId = req.user.id;
      const path = req.file;

      const user = await User.findById(userId);
      user.profilePicture = path;
      await user.save();

      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ message: "Profile picture uploaded successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: "An error occurred while uploading the profile picture",
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Every time I select an image and click `Submit` I'm getting the default error which isn't saying much so I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong. The image itself seems to be correctly uploading but I'm not getting any values for my `profilePicture`. The code is meant to take the `path` of my image, change it to my `id` and add it to my `profilePicture` value in my `User` schema.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  profilePicture: String,
});
```

Comment: "Every time I select an image and click Submit I'm getting the default error which isn't saying much so I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong." - Then **look at the `error` variable!** You created it to store the error and then you completely ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `req.file.path` not `req.file`

```
const path = req.file.path;
```